# How to proccess mutiple result sets from one postgres function in libpqxx

Tags: postgresql, cursor, libpqxx

I have a postgres function returning three different result sets (using three refcursors - all three result sets have differing numbers/types of columns).  I want to call this function from libpqxx, but it's not clear to me how to do this.   It's not clear how libpqxx would know when the rows coming down have changed from one cursor to the next.  If anyone has any advice (or examples), it would be much appreciated.

The postgres function returning the three refcursors works as expected (from within psql), but I can't get the pqxx exec() to work.

Thanks in advance...